# TypeError : .next() is not a function

Tags: javascript, iterator, typeerror

```
dataArr = []
let element;

function Users()
 {

    let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api'
    fetch(url).then((response) =>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data) =>{
         
        dataArr.push(data['results']);
    })
}



for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    Users()
}

console.log(dataArr);


function profileIter(values) {

    let nextIndex = 0;
    if(nextIndex < values.length){
        return {
            value: values[nextIndex++],
            done: false
        }
    }
    else{
        return {
            done: true
        }
    }}


const CVIter = profileIter(dataArr);


console.log(CVIter.next().value);
```

After running this I got an error saying

> CVIter.next() is not a function

[image: check this image out]

Comment: `profileIter` doesnt return an object that has a `next()` function

Comment: Turning the question around... Why do you expect `next` to be a function on that object?  What are you expecting that function to do?

Comment: I predict other problems later, `fetch` being asynchronous, you'll wonder why `dataArr` is empty (just so that you have the good keywords to search on this many-times-aswered issue)

Comment: There is a function users which requests data of random users from an api 
I am requesting 5 times such data and want an iterator so that i can log the data of the users one by one - @David

Comment: @DanielA.White but profileIter is an iterator and it does return an object

Comment: @Nav: Why can't you just loop over `dataArr`?  (Note also from a previous comment... In the current code `dataArr` will be empty when you try.)

Comment: @Nav it is not. run thru your debugger...

Comment: Ok now i get it...Do u mean that since Iterator is fetch is asynchronous when the code runs the CVIter.next() ... dataArr is empty and this is why it shows that error ..?? @David

Comment: @Nav: No.  You're getting the error because `profileIter` returns an object literal which has no `next` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `profileIter` function is returning an `IteratorResult` object, not an iterator, so the `next()` function is not present.

If you want to get an iterator, you have to make your `profileIter` a generator like this:

```js
function * profileIter(values) {
    for (let nextIndex = 0; nextIndex < values.length; ++nextIndex){
        yield values[nextIndex];
    }
}
```

or make your function to return an iterator

```js
function profileIter(values) {
    let nextIndex = 0;

    return {
        next: () => {
            if (nextIndex < values.length){
                return {
                    value: values[nextIndex++],
                    done: false
                };
            }

            return {
                done: true
            };
        },
    };
}
```